# Meaning of Java DelayQueue Unbounded

Tags: java

According to the documentation, a JAVA DelayQueue is unbounded. Which means that it has no upper bound.

How does JAVA DelayQueue handle not going out of memory? How can we just keep adding elements without having to worry about exceeding heap space?

Or should we be checking the size of the DelayQueue and handle maintaining some upper bound of total elements ourselves?

Comment: Unbounded doesn't mean you can't run out of memory.

Comment: What do you think is the best way we can ensure that we don't have a situation which may lead to memory becoming full due to a DelayQueue.

Comment: By being careful when you design and program.

Comment: Either you functionally make sure it can't happen (somehow assert that the debit of Delayed being consumed is always greater - or in average greater and never lesser for too long - than the debit of Delayed pushed into the queue), or you use a bounded queue instead... or you accept to have an OOMError once in a while